# Usar variable en otra función con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, app, framework7

Primero que todo voy a dejar un enlace donde pueden ver el ejemplo funcionando de manera completa.
[Enlace a la pagina AQUI](http://judasniper.neocities.org/advance/index.html)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El valor elegido en esta lista. determina cual valor del power se va mostrar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un `input` de tipo `range` que uso para calcular el peso de una persona:

```
 <div class="item-input">
              <div class="range-slider">
                <h2  id='Peso1' >Peso:</h2>  
                  <input type="range" oninput="mouseDown(); "  min="3.5" max="50" value="12.5" step ="0.50" >
                </div>
          </div>
```

Entonces tengo esta función que me devuelve el dato:

```
function mouseDown() {
    var el = document.getElementById('Articulo1');
    el.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
        document.getElementById('Peso1').innerHTML = (e.target.value);
    });
}
```

Lo que necesito es poder multiplicar el valor **e** por el valor **power**

Pero no se como hacerlo.

```
cars: [
            {
                vendor: 'Volkswagen',
                model: 'Passat',
                power: 152,
                speed: 280,
                weight: 1400,
                color: 'black',
                year: 2012,
                description: ''

            },
            {
                vendor: 'Skoda',
                model: 'Superb',
                power: 152,
                speed: 260,
                weight: 1600,
                color: 'white',
                year: 2013,
                description: ''
            },
             {
                vendor: 'Amoxicilina',
                model: 'Suspension',
                power: 250,
                speed: 50,
                weight: "B",
                color: 'white',
                year: 2013,
                description: 'Infeccion del tracto respiratorio, urogenital y gastrointestinal, de la region ORL, de la piel, ifecciones geniologicas, gonorrea, leptospirosis, fiebre tofoidea'

            },
```

---

Este es mi código completo:

```js
// Let's register Template7 helper so we can pass json string in links
Template7.registerHelper('json_stringify', function (context) {
    return JSON.stringify(context);
});

// Initialize your app
var myApp = new Framework7({
    animateNavBackIcon: true,
    // Enable templates auto precompilation
    precompileTemplates: true,
    // Enabled pages rendering using Template7
    template7Pages: true,
    // Specify Template7 data for pages
    template7Data: {
        // Will be applied for page with "projects.html" url
        'url:projects.html': {
            firstname: 'Josue',
            lastname: 'Gonzalez',
            age: 30,
            position: 'Tecnico de Salud en Farmacia',
            company: 'Area de Salud Limon',
            interests: ['Un buen Cafe', 'Helado', 'Viajar', 'HTML', 'apps', 'footbol'],
            projects: [
                {
                    title: 'Matris de interacciones con busqueda facil',
                    description: ''
                },
                {
                    title: 'PediaDosis',
                    description: 'Aplicacion web para el calculo de dosis pediatricas'
                },
                {
                    // title: 'Android',
                    // description: 'Mobile operating system'
                }
            ]
        },

        // Will be applied for page with data-page="contacts"
        'page:contacts': {
            tel: '(506)+ 8308-2587',
            email: 'jgonzalb@ccss.sa.cr',
            country: 'Costa Rica',
            city: 'Puerto Limon',
            // zip: '12345',
            // street: 'Awesome st'
        },

        // Just plain data object that we can pass for other pages using data-contextName attribute
        cars: [
            {
                vendor: 'Volkswagen',
                model: 'Passat',
                power: 152,
                speed: 280,
                weight: 1400,
                color: 'black',
                year: 2012,
                description: ''

            },
            {
                vendor: 'Skoda',
                model: 'Superb',
                power: 152,
                speed: 260,
                weight: 1600,
                color: 'white',
                year: 2013,
                description: ''
            },
             {
                vendor: 'Amoxicilina',
                model: 'Suspension',
                power: 250,
                speed: 50,
                weight: "B",
                color: 'white',
                year: 2013,
                description: 'Infeccion del tracto respiratorio, urogenital y gastrointestinal, de la region ORL, de la piel, ifecciones geniologicas, gonorrea, leptospirosis, fiebre tofoidea'

            },
            {
                vendor: 'Ford',
                model: 'Mustang',
                power: 480,
                speed: 320,
                weight: 1200,
                color: 'red',
                year: 2014,
                description: ''
            },
        ],

        // Another plain data object, used in "about" link in data-contextName object 
        about: {
            name: 'Josue Gonzalez',
            age: 30,
            position: 'Tecnico de Salud en Farmacia',
            company: 'Area de Salud Limon',
            interests: ['Un buen Cafe', 'Helado', 'Apps Mobiles', 'Html', 'Footbal', 'Viajar']
        }
    }
});

// Export selectors engine
var $$ = Dom7;

// Add main View
var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main', {
    // Enable dynamic Navbar
    dynamicNavbar: true,
});

function mouseDown(){
    var el = document.getElementById('Articulo1');
    el.addEventListener('input', function(e) { 
    document.getElementById('Peso1').innerHTML=(e.target.value);
});
}



function outputUpdate(vol) {
    document.querySelector('#volume').value = vol;
   
}



var x = 5;
var y = 6;
var z= x+y;
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = z;
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="left sliding"><a href="#" class="back link"> <i class="icon icon-back"></i><span>Back</span></a></div>
    <div class="center sliding">{{vendor}} {{model}}</div>
    <div class="right"><a href="#" class="link icon-only open-panel"> <i class="icon icon-bars"></i></a></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pages">
  <div data-page="car" class="page" >
    <div class="page-content">
      <div class="content-block" id="Articulo1">
        <div class="content-block-inner" >
          <h3>{{vendor}} {{model}}</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><b>Presentacion</b> - {{power}} mg / 5ml</li>
            <li id="para1"><b>Dosis Maxima</b> - {{speed}} mg/kg/dia - cada 8 horas</li>
            <li><b>Embarazo</b> - {{weight}} </li>
             <li><b>Color</b> - {{color}}</li>
            <li><b>Year</b> - {{year}}</li>
            <li><strong>IND</strong> -{{description}}</li>
            
          </ul>
        </div>
            <div class="item-input">
                  <div class="range-slider">
                    <h2  id='Peso1' >Peso:</h2>  
                      <input type="range" oninput="mouseDown(); "  min="3.5" max="50" value="12.5" step ="0.50" >
                    </div>
              </div>
<p id="demo"></p>





    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Josue, no comprendo cómo determinas cuál **power** usas en el método `mouseDown();`

Comment: ok, Entiendo que es algo confuso... Power es un dato que se muestra en en el front cuyo valor es llamado por el codigo html asi. `<li><b>Presentacion</b> - {{power}} mg / 5ml</li>`

Comment: Josue, por favor, actualiza tu pregunta, los comentarios son temporales. Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando selecciones un producto, *además de colocar el **power** en esta parte de tu programa:*

```
<li><b>Presentacion</b> - {{power}} mg / 5ml</li>
```

Coloca el **power** en otro elemento HTML.

Te sugiero agregar al código HTML un `input` de tipo `hidden` cuyo valor será el **power** del producto seleccionado.

Ejemplo:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdf_PowerProducto" value="200" />
```

Luego, modifica tu lógica para obtener el valor del `hdf_PowerProducto` y operarlo como desees:

Este sería el resultado:

```
// Crear una variable que almacenará el power del producto seleccionado:
var powerProducto = 0;

// En tu código -- donde imprimes los valores del producto seleccionado
// asigna el valor a la variable (powerProducto).


// Modifica tu lógica así:
function mouseDown() {
    var el = document.getElementById('Articulo1');
    el.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
        document.getElementById('Peso1').innerHTML = powerProducto * (e.target.value);
    });
}
```

Comment: Exelente.... Funciono. Gracias Por la ayuda.

Comment: @JosueGonzalez, me alegro que te haya funcionado. Si esta pregunta solucionó tu problema, considera marcar esta respuesta como respuesta aceptada. Saludos.

Comment: Listo mau. Saludos